# Story arc for introduction of aliens with their own story

Tags: aliens, races

Apologies if this has been asked before, but it has been bugging me as I finally move toward the point of releasing my novels and not just writing for myself. Many of my stories involve humans interacting with mysterious species and moments that show while they are able to search the stars, they are the weakest gnats out there, compared to beings that have thousands of worlds, and wars that have killed trillions.

The issue I have is, I want to step away from just telling you about these species by how the humans interact with them, and what happens after this. For one thing, they have their own characters and are supposed to symbolise a lot more than just human characters can. So, their collision would be significant, but from both species' sides.

The biggest problem I have with writing books that make sure to be distinct from humans, and exist in their own slang, physical constraints and ideologies, is that the readers always find it hard to connect.

Would people say from experience the human-centric perspective is always going to work? Hence, why Star Wars and Star Trek can only ever venture away from just the humans with a heavy-handed link already existing.

Thank you to anyone that will contribute.
Sorry if the question is a repetition

Comment: [*The Gods Themselves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves) by Isaac Asimov has a middle part which takes place in one of the most alien worlds ever described, and is narrated by some of most alien characters ever. And it won a Nebula _and_ a Hugo.

Comment: While interesting, this has two problems.  One, it seems more like a discussion question than something with an objective answer.  Two, what does it have to do with Worldbuilding?  You aren't asking how to make workable aliens, you're asking how to get your readers to relate to your characters.

Comment: While it is interesting, this topic is not about worldbuilding. This question is better asked in Writer.SE.

Comment: @Vylix, I think it is borderline Worldbuilding. A writer might ask "should part of the story be told from the viewpoint of the antagonists?" Here we have "how to present the *truly* alien?"

Comment: @o.m. Would people say from experience the human-centric perspective is always going to work? That's asking for pov, which is the topic of writer, not wb.

Comment: This is a reasonable body of fiction from an alien perspective. John Brunner's *The Crucible of Time* springs to mind. Remember you can show you aliens meeting humans from the alien's point of view. This is one way to introduce them into your story arc. Particularly if you show the same scene from each other's perspective. While writing about humans is easier than aliens, it's the writing that makes it work.

Comment: I can't say for other people, but I am always more interested in reading books written from very different perspectives. I also greatly appreciate if an author manages to show aliens as truly alien and not just humans with alien faces as in StarTrek and other sci-fi. So, you have at least one eager reader :)

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about insistent/oppressive slang use. As the writer, you spend **much** more time with your world than the reader. How much does a casual reader have to learn about your background to understand the story? How do you present this information?

- [A few key terms](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FantasticHonorifics) might help to drive home that *we're not in Kansas any more.* Especially if they can be understood from context.
- You speak about novels, plural, and not just a novel. What happens if a reader picks up volume two or three in the bookstore? Will it be comprehensible at all?
- There are some long-running series with a cast of characters and a glossary of terms in the back of each volume. When this hits fifty pages or more, one has to wonder about the editing.

Are the aliens [comprehensible](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StarfishAliens) to a human reader? If you try to make their POV understandable, you might be drive their alienness home, or you might humanize them.